# Apt-get doesn't work anymore

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, aptitude

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 
Whenever I try to do an sudo apt-get install I get this error

(this example is for sudo apt-get install virtualbox)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting virtualbox-3.2 instead of virtualbox
virtualbox-3.2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up apache (1.3.34-2ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing apache (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up lynx (2.8.5-2ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/lynx doesn't exist.
dpkg: error processing lynx (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache
 lynx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: In this process your apache & lynx will be removed and reinstalled**

try following
**This should remove your apache & lynx**

sudo dpkg -r lynx

sudo dpkg -r apache

then try

sudo apt-get -f autoremove

sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install apache2 lynx

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your apache and lynx installation.  It's hard to say what broke, or why.  You could try removing lynx and apache and reinstalling them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can install and upgrade packages as long as they don't depend on `lynx` or `apache`. Nonetheless you should resolve this as soon as possible.

The installation process for both packages is blocked because the post-installation scripts are returning an error. You need to fix or work around each error.

For `lynx`, the message `alternative path /usr/bin/lynx doesn't exist` indicates that something is wrong with your current installation of lynx. It's possible that merely upgrading the package to the version in 10.04 will fix the problem, so try that first (`apt-get install lynx-cur lynx`). Otherwise the easiest way to fix this may well be to remove the `lynx` package and reinstall it.

For `apache`, you also currently have the version from 8.04 installed. If you were upgrading anyway, first try getting the latest version: `apt-get install apache`. If that doesn't work, you'll need to figure out what precisely is causing the error. Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/apache.postinst` and add `set -x` as the second line of the file, then run `dpkg --configure apache` and watch the trace. If you can't figure out what's wrong, post that trace.

Comment: when trying to apt-get install lynx i get E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @Asaf: Add `set -x` to `/var/lib/dpkg/info/lynx.prerm` and post the resulting error message. Also post the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/lynx* /etc/alternatives/lynx*` and the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/lynx`.